# connectedAndroidtest mergeAndroidReports not working

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I'm trying to run two different sets of instrumentation tests in two different modules. It's my understanding that if I add the `mergeAndroidReports` command to each of these test tasks that in the root project in the build folder I should see a test report which combines all tests run.

At this moment I see a test report in each module created as well as a blank test report created at the project level build folder.

It appears it's setting up the blank report to combine but not actually completing the report. Has anyone run into issues using the `mergeAndroidReports` command?

Extra info:

I have the following added to the project level `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'android-reporting'
```

Again there are no errors and I do see the following directories are being generated at the project level:

```
build/reports/androidTests/index.html
```

But this is empty: nothing is added to this report.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same problem

Comment: I also have a same issue

Comment: I met the same issue. If you open the `index.html` via `Open in browser` -> `Chrome` in Android Studio, then you may get an empty content though you have the correct test results. I tried to manually open the file via my file explorer then this issue solved.

Comment: Same problem here ... any ideas why this is happening?